# How to show checked radio button in Razor edit view Asp net core mvc

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, radio-button, asp.net-core-mvc

Despite of Asp net core code in Razor view:

```
@model List<SelectListItem>
<form asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Change" method="post">
    @foreach (SelectListItem item in Model) {
        <br />
        <input asp-for="@item.Value" type="radio" value="@item.Value" /> @(item.Value + " - " + item.Text)
   }
   <br />
   <input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>
```

all radio buttons are checked in browser -> view source

```
<input type="radio" value="1001" checked="checked" id="item_Value" name="item.Value" /> 1001 - Vilnius<br />
<input type="radio" value="1002" checked="checked" id="item_Value" name="item.Value" /> 1002 - Palanga<br />
```

How it can be all radio buttons checked?

Added:

```
var lst = new List<SelectListItem>() {
           new SelectListItem {
                Value = "1001",
                Text = "Vilnius",
                Selected = true
            },
            new SelectListItem {
                Value = "1002",
                Text = "Trakai",
                Selected = false
            }
        };
```

Comment: Can you provide what kind of `List<SelectListItem>` passed to view? I think it's not a good idea to have `List<SelectListItem>` for `@model` directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the `checked="checked"` attribute is set because the current value of those radio buttons are equal to model value (the property you're assigned in `asp-for` attribute inside tag helper). Hence, your current setup with `asp-for="@item.Value"` is wrong here:

```
<input asp-for="@item.Value" type="radio" value="@item.Value" />
```

If you want to set their values based on `Selected` property inside `SelectListItem` instance, you need to use a property from your viewmodel class into `asp-for` attribute (the property must defined as value type or string).

Below is a proper example setup:

**Model**

```
// Viewmodel class
public class ViewModel
{
    // used to store selected value in select tag helper
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> OptionList { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller action**

```
// Populate select list
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Change()
{
    var model = new ViewModel();
    model.OptionList = new List<SelectListItem>();

    // populate list values here
    model.OptionList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "1001", Value = "Vilnius", Selected = true });
    model.OptionList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "1002", Value = "Trakai", Selected = false });

    return View(model);
}
```

**View**

```
@* Set viewmodel property into tag helper *@
@model ViewModel

<form asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Change" method="post">
    @foreach (var item in Model.OptionList) 
    {
        <br />
        <input asp-for="SelectedValue" type="radio" value="@item.Value" /> @(item.Value + " - " + item.Text)
    }
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>
```

Related issue:

[Radio Button Tag Helper sets every radio button to checked](https://forums.asp.net/t/2120382.aspx?Radio%20Button%20Tag%20Helper%20sets%20every%20radio%20button%20to%20checked)

Comment: All radio button has checked!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. In my case

```
<input asp-for="@item.Value" type="radio" value="@item.Value" /> @(item.Value + " - " + item.Text)
```

change to

```
<input asp-for="@item.Text" type="radio" value="@item.Value" /> @(item.Value + " - " + item.Text)
```

and in controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> ChangeKomanda(SelectListItem item) {
   // use item.Text instead of item.Value
```

May it help someone